# Update route cache on all servers behind load balancer

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, caching, routes

I am working on a Laravel project which has a massive amount of routes. The app runs on 2 servers behind a load balancer. I have cached the routes to make the site run faster. There are instances when I have to make the routes update programmatically. I know the cached route file is located in `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`

The problem is that when I call

```php
Artisan::call('route:cache');
```

It will update the route file on the current server and the other server will not get updated. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: create a webhook for cache route then via `ip` address route you can trigger both

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kamlesh. That is something I will consider. Respect.